# Why isn't React Native Drawer being triggered using React Native Router Flux + Redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, reactjs

I am using the following components to create a React Native + Redux app:

- [React Native Router Flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)
- [React Native Drawer](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer)

I tried following exactly the [example provided on how to implement the drawer](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/OTHER_INFO.md), yet when navigating to where the drawer should be displayed, using `Actions.drawer`, I get the error:

[image]

But if I try to navigate to the Scene, via `Actions.home`, inside the drawer Scene, nothing happens but the action `REACT_NATIVE_ROUTER_FLUX_RESET` is still being called via `redux-logger`.

**Tried following the example exactly but no luck. What could I be doing wrong?**

Here is my set up for scene using Redux:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  ActionConst,
  Actions,
  Router,
  Scene,
} from 'react-native-router-flux'
import {
  Provider,
  connect,
} from 'react-redux'

import configureStore from './store/configureStore'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Home from './components/Home'
import NavDrawer from './components/NavDrawer'

const RouterWithRedux = connect()(Router)
const store = configureStore()

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux>
          <Scene key='root'>
            <Scene component={Login} initial={true} key='login' title='Login'/>
            <Scene key="drawer" component={NavDrawer}>
              <Scene component={Home} key='home' title='Home' type='reset' initial={true}/>
            </Scene>
          </Scene>
        </RouterWithRedux>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Then I press a button in Login and it triggers `Actions.` to navigate to.

The NavDrawer is:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer'
import { Actions, DefaultRenderer } from 'react-native-router-flux'

import NavDrawerPanel from './NavDrawerPanel'

export default class NavDrawer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', ref: this.refs.navigation});
  }

  render() {
    const children = state.children;

    return (
      <Drawer
        ref="navigation"
        type="displace"
        content={<NavDrawerPanel />}
        tapToClose
        openDrawerOffset={0.2}
        panCloseMask={0.2}
        negotiatePan
        tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({
          main: { opacity: Math.max(0.54, 1 - ratio) },
        })}
      >
        <DefaultRenderer
          navigationState={children[0]}
          onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate}
        />
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

And NavDrawerPanel is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {PropTypes} from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const NavDrawerPanel = (props, context) => {
  const drawer = context.drawer;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={Actions.home}>
        <Text>Home Page</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={Actions.login}>
        <Text>Login Page</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
})
```

**EDIT**
Here are what's being imported where the Scene + Redux is set up:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  ActionConst,
  Actions,
  Router,
  Scene,
} from 'react-native-router-flux'
import {
  Provider,
  connect,
} from 'react-redux'

import configureStore from './store/configureStore'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Home from './components/Home'
import NavDrawer from './components/NavDrawer'
```

**EDIT 2 - console.log(this.props)**

Doing console.log(this.props) in component Login:
[image]

When Actions.home() from component Login:
[image]

When Actions.drawer() from component Login:
[image]

**EDIT 3 - console.log(this.props) inside NavDrawer.js**

The NavDrawer never gets rendered so console.log(this.props) doesn't get logged

But with console.log(this.props) inside NavDrawer.js and Actions.home, I get:

[image]

And with console.log(this.props) inside NavDrawer.js and Actions.drawer, I get:

[image]

Comment: are you sure you are importing everything correctly?

Comment: @Gazta Yes, exactly how shown in the original post. Could the problem be that the drawer needs to be implemented differently since it has a redux set up?

Comment: post the rest of the file where you are setting up the scene

Comment: @Gazta Did so under EDIT in the original post. Hopefully that gives a clue...

Comment: @Gazta Checking to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in this but I'm using react-native-router-flux and react-native-drawer in my application without any problems. Some of the differences I see between your code and mine are:

1. You have two scenes set to `initial={true}`. This might mess up the Router.
2. I don't navigate directly to the drawer using `Actions.drawer` but instead I navigate to the home scene using `Actions.home`.

If nothing of these works, could you share the `render()` function of your home component?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue but you don't seem to be importing TouchableHighlight on the NavDrawerPanel component, so:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight
} from "react-native";
```

Comment: Sorry it was imported but just missed it when copying the code over. To me the error might something to do with `DefaultRenderer`? But can't seem to make out what is wrong

Comment: Checking to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you pass in wrong value to navigationState in DefaultRenderer.
It should be

`const { navigationState: { children } } = this.props;`

In your NavDrawer class

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer'
import { Actions, DefaultRenderer } from 'react-native-router-flux'

import NavDrawerPanel from './NavDrawerPanel'

export default class NavDrawer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', ref: this.refs.navigation});
  }

  render() {
    //const children = state.children; //wrong
    const { navigationState: { children } } = this.props;
    return (
      <Drawer
        ref="navigation"
        type="displace"
        content={<NavDrawerPanel />}
        tapToClose
        openDrawerOffset={0.2}
        panCloseMask={0.2}
        negotiatePan
        tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({
          main: { opacity: Math.max(0.54, 1 - ratio) },
        })}
      >
        <DefaultRenderer
          navigationState={children[0]}
          onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate}
        />
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion and gave it an attempt, but unfortunately still getting the error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of 'DefaultRenderer'`. I'm assuming the error has to do with `DefaultRenderer` but still can't seem to figure out what exactly

Comment: Please let me know if you've seen my last comment.

Comment: Can you post your home component code and log the output of navigationState when navigate to home and drawer scene? Where you call Actions.home() and Action.drawer() from? By the way, you should not navigate to drawer scene using Actions.drawer() as the scenes wrap in your drawer scene in your router config will contain drawer

Comment: Sure thing. Just added three screenshots of the logs. First one is when the application starts up and does `console.log(this.props)`. Second one is when I try to navigate to `home` using `Actions.home` from Login component Scene. Third is when I try to navigate to `drawer` using `Actions.drawer` from Login component Scene. As for the home component code, it is purely just text in the middle saying Home and nothing more.

Comment: can you show log of navigationState by `console.log(this.props)` in your NavDrawer component?

Comment: Tried `console.log(this.props)` inside `NavDrawer` component, but it never gets rendered so does not log anything. But I took screenshots of the actions taken, with `Actions.home` and `Actions.drawer`. Updated the original post so please take a look. Also to clarify, I should always be doing `Actions.home` and not `Actions.drawer`, cause the `drawer` is simply a wrapper?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong about navigation to drawer scene using Actions.drawer(). With react-native-router-flux, currently you can only navigate to current scene sibling, which in your case, you will need to use Actions.drawer to navigate from your login scene. Refer issue in [https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1102](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1102)
If your code is working fine, when u navigate to drawer scene, the navigationState.children in NavDrawer component should not be empty

Comment: No worries, there is always something to learn. Appreciate the issue reference but was not able to pick up anything helpful. Could `React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number.` give any clues? In my last screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still something you're working on, but for any others using these libraries, you definitely don't want to use the drawer as a scene. It should wrap you whole router like so:

```
<Drawer
    ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
    type="displace"
    useInteractionManager
    content={
      <SideMenuContent
        open={this.state.sideMenuOpen}
        openDrawer={this.openDrawer}
        closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer}
      />
    }
    tapToClose
    openDrawerOffset={0.08}
    negotiatePan
    onOpenStart={() => { this.setState({ sideMenuOpen: true }); }}
    onClose={() => { this.setState({ sideMenuOpen: false }); }}
  >
    <RouterWithRedux
      scenes={this.scenes}
    />
  </Drawer>
```

That's how we have it wired up, and it works well. Then, we just pass these function into our scenes as needed:

```
openDrawer = () => {
  this.drawer.open();
}

closeDrawer = () => {
  this.drawer.close();
}
```